# Multidimensional Arrays of expected length

Tags: python

Is it possible to create an multidimensional array with this content:

```
expected = [
    [[0, 600], [0, 600]],
    [[600, 1200], [0, 600]],
    [[0, 600], [600, 1200]],
    [[600, 1200], [600, 1200]]
]
```

with for-loops? and if yes, how?

edit:

I found a solution

```
steps = 600
storage = []
for i in range(0, 1200):
    if i % steps == 0:
        for j in range(0, 1200):
            if j % steps == 0:
                storage.append([[j, j + steps], [i, i + steps]])
print(storage == expected)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-on-demand service, where work orders are given and people code for you. Someone may very well answer this question before it gets closed, but it reduces the site's usefulness for everyone when they do.

Comment: `range()` can have a step argument: `range(0, 1200, 600)` makes more sense here.